# Find the short-lived process that is polling my port?

Tags: linux, process, netstat, strace

I've noticed one of the headless computers in my network is constantly polling the VNC port on another computer. My problem is, that when I see the port from which it has connected (with tcpdump) and try to find the process with `netstat -anp|grep PORT`, the process is already killed and nothing is found (the process seems to live for less than a millisecond).

Is there something similar to tcpdump that would report process names & PIDs? Or some smart way of doing strace to capture the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try auditctl, it will help. Enabling below rule can flood your system so use just form debugging.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S execve
```

reference : https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`sysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/).  With that, you can watch for system calls involving connections to a specific port.  For example, assuming that the VNC server is listening on port 5901:

```
$ sudo sysdig and fd.sip=<SERVER_IP> and fd.sport=5901
```

That will generate output for any process interacting with the given SERVER_IP on the given port.  It will include the process name and pid by default.  The [user guide](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-User-Guide) includes more information about the available filters and what information can be included in the output.